# How to set up initialRange on Vue-rangedate-picker-winslow?

Tags: vue.js, components

While using [Vue Rangedate Picker](https://github.com/gwindes/vue-rangedate-picker-winslow) I hit a roadblock trying to configure the prop Initial Range (the initial range that the component spits before the user even select any other range).

Have managed to setup other props like "caption" and "preset ranges" but the initRange is complaining about it not being an Object and being a function.

[image]

On my template:

```
<date-picker v-bind="datePicker" initRange="datePicker.presetRanges.last7Days" @selected="onDateSelected" i18n="EN" ></date-picker>
```

On my data:

```
 datePicker: {
        initRange: {
            start: '1505862000000',
            end: '1505872000000'             
        },
        captions: {
            title: 'Choose Date/Period',
            ok_button: 'Apply'
        },
         presetRanges: {
             today: function () {
                const n = new Date()
                const startToday = new Date(n.getFullYear(), n.getMonth(), n.getDate() + 1, 0, 0)
                const endToday = new Date(n.getFullYear(), n.getMonth(), n.getDate() + 1, 23, 59)
                return {
                    label: 'Today',
                    active: false,
                    dateRange: {
                        start: startToday,
                        end: endToday
                    }
                }
            },
            last7Days: function () {
                const n = new Date()
                const weekAgo = new Date(n.getFullYear(), n.getMonth(), n.getDate() - 7, 24, 0)
                const endToday = new Date(n.getFullYear(), n.getMonth(), n.getDate() + 1, 0, 0)
                return {
                    label: 'Last 7 Days', 
                    active: 'false', 
                    dateRange: {start: weekAgo,   end: endToday}
                }
            },
```

On my methods:

```
methods: {
onDateSelected: function (daterange) {
    let that = this;
  that.selectedDate = daterange;
    let UnixStart = Math.round((Date.parse(that.selectedDate.start)));
    let UnixEnd = Math.round((Date.parse(that.selectedDate.end)));
},
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bliblidotcom/vue-rangedate-picker/issues/71
I leave the comments with this link. you will find it. should work for you.

Comment: It's worked for me. Try like this:
Use this forked version instead of the origin version.
https://github.com/gwindes/vue-rangedate-picker-winslow
(this week as default )
<vue-rangedate-picker :initRange="datePickerConfig.initRange"
const datePickerConfig = {
initRange: {
start: moment().startOf('week').add(2,'days')._d,
end: moment().startOf('week').add(8,'days')._d
}
}

Comment: It would be much easier to read that code if you included it in your answer rather than adding it as a comment